# React useEffect is goes inside of infinite loops

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a vertical stepper for form submission. There is an issue in Stepper.jsx inside of useEffect it setStepsState(stepState);. The programs continuous run

when i remove dependency list from useEffect it runs properly but it does not pass the update value.

Here is codesandbox link [codesanbok](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-snow-6615c?file=/src/Stepper.js:738-747)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./Stepper.scss";

const Stepper = ({
  stepColor,
  steps,
  direction,
  currentStep,
  setStepsState
}) => {
  const [stepState, setStepState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let createSteps = steps.map((step, idx) => ({
      description: step.label,
      component: step.component,
      completed: idx < currentStep - 1, // past are completed
      selected: idx <= currentStep - 1, // past & present are colored
      highlighted: idx === currentStep - 1 // only present is highlighted
    }));
    setStepState(createSteps);
  }, [steps, currentStep]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stepState) setStepsState(stepState);
  }, [stepState]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={`stepper-wrapper-${direction}`}>
        {stepState.map(
          (
            { selected, completed, highlighted, description, component },
            idx
          ) => (
            <div className="step-wrapper" key={idx}>
              <div
                className={`step-number step-number-${
                  selected ? "active" : "disabled"
                }`}
                style={{ background: `${selected ? stepColor : "none"}` }}
              >
                {completed ? "✔" : idx + 1}
              </div>
              <div
                className={`step-description ${
                  highlighted ? "step-description-active" : ""
                }`}
              >
                {description}
              </div>

              {idx + 1 !== stepState.length && (
                <div
                  className={`divider-line divider-line-${stepState.length}`}
                />
              )}
            </div>
          )
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

Stepper.propTypes = {
  direction: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  steps: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default Stepper;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is totally pointless:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (stepState) setStepsState(stepState);
}, [stepState]);
```

You pass `setStepsState` as prop and also define it as local state setter.

In your sandbox you duplicate logic and state in App and Step, use either App or Step to put the logic in, not both.

Here is an example where logic and state are maintained in App:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;
const Stepper = ({ steps }) => {
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(steps, undefined, 2)}</pre>;
};
const steps = [
  { label: 'step 1', component: 'component 1' },
  { label: 'step 2', component: 'component 2' },
  { label: 'step 3', component: 'component 3' },
];
const createSteps = (currentStep) =>
  steps.map((step, idx) => ({
    description: step.label,
    component: step.component,
    completed: idx < currentStep - 1, // past are completed
    selected: idx <= currentStep - 1, // past & present are colored
    highlighted: idx === currentStep - 1, // only present is highlighted
  }));
const App = () => {
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = React.useState(1);
  const [stepsState, setsStepState] = useState(
    createSteps(currentStep)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setsStepState(createSteps(currentStep));
  }, [currentStep]);
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1)}
      >
        next step
      </button>
      <Stepper steps={stepsState} />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```